# How can I get the most out of Shock Pulse?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

In *Diablo 3*, the Wizard has a signature spell called Shock Pulse. This spell causes a (seemingly) random burst of lightning on the ground in front of you.

The problem with this is that it is a) uncontrollable, and 2) extremely limited in range. Due to the Wizard being exceptionally squishy, it's very beneficial to not let the enemies get close to me, keeping them out of range for this limited attack.

**How do I make this spell worth using? Should I just avoid it altogether?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Piercing Orb is one of the few signature spells that will go through all the enemies, you can rune Shock Pulse for that later on. I also liked it earlier when my wizard could go toe to toe in normal difficulty, using Pulse with the Explosive Bolts rune that does corpse explosion.

As a lightning spell, it also has a synergy with Paralysis (8% chance to stun for 2 secs).

Comment: I used Exploding Bolts 100% of the time once I got it (still very early in Nightmare so I dunno if it holds up).  Tore holes in groups like crazy.

Comment: I think that is probably the biggest damage dealer in signature spells, when facing a crowd of enemies - and the more that die, more of their brethren will also die sooner & explode! I haven't been able to use it much due to speccing too much MF & too less life (so I need to stay far), but I am moving things around and may give it another go.